# I want to send state from react to redux hooks how i do it

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having a bit of a redux so I'm using this hooks more convenient

I have some files

This is my reducer

```
import UserName from '../NAVBAR/log_in'
const initialState = {
    username: UserName
};

export function userReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    console.log('USER-action', action);
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'USER_NAME':
            return {
                ...state,
                username: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

This is my login file

I put >>>>>>> to make it clearer

```
function Login(props) {
    var classes = useStyles();
    var [username, setUsername] = useState('')
    var [password, setPassword] = useState('')

    var dispatch = useDispatch();

    >>>>>>const UserName = useSelector((state) => state.username);

       >>>>>>>>>> Sign in:-{props.UserName}</Typography>
                        <TextField
                            variant="outlined"
                            margin="normal"
                            fullWidth
                            value={username}
                            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                 >>>>>>>>>>>onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'USER_NAME', payload: username })}

                        />
```

**IMAGE**
[View post on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USvLp.jpg)

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

And if you need a picture or something else I'll upload

Comment: What is `onClick` in TextField ? I guess we mostly have methods like `onFocus, onBlur & onChange` only.

Comment: Moving dispatch to `onChange` or `onBlur` should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot the answer was *onBlur*

Comment: Good to know that.

Answer (score 0):

With this setup, the local state and redux state seem redundant.

Either modify your `onChange` to dispatch your action, or add a submit button that dispatches your actions to update redux. But if this is as complex as your form gets, I'd just skip the local state, and have your form read and update redux only.

Comment: I really want to work with redux so I will delete it when it works

Comment: If you do remove the local state, you'll need to switch it to `onChange` and your value will become `UserName`. But if you leave it as is then you're correct that `onBlur` is the best choice.